# ionic pro package failure: Failed to install android SDK Platform 26

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using the new Ionic Pro. I have migrated my previously working ionic app to the new Pro services. I am now able to successfully push my code to my ionic pro git repo and I can see the build log on the dashboard. The build completes successfully. Once that is done, I navigate to the Package tab for said build. I configure my package to compile **platform=Android version=Release Security Profile=Android Release security profile.**

The output log at this point moves through the installation process and gets the following console output.

```
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

The build process then appears to start a Gradle Daemon and ultimately ends up with this output

```
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to 
be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
at
```

build_dczd6dp0q9phbzjp0lgrh3ndj.run(/usr/src/app/platforms/android/build.gradle:142)
    File /home/gitlab-runner/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
    Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 26 in /opt/android-
    sdk/licenses
    License for package Android SDK Platform 26 accepted.
    Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 26".
    Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Failed to install the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Platform 26]
  The SDK directory (/opt/android-sdk) is not writeable,
  please update the directory permissions.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --
debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 33.48 secs
Error: /usr/src/app/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 
1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Failed to install the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Platform 26]
  The SDK directory (/opt/android-sdk) is not writeable,
  please update the directory permissions.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --
debug option to get more log output.
Failed to upload apk to storage please retry your build.
Running after script...
$ clean-up
Cleaning up files...
Successful clean up
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I am not clear as to what this error means or how I can resolve it using ionic pro. The build works for me locally.

The following is my ionic info

```
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.10.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.10.3

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 7.0.1

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 2.3.0

System:

    Node : v7.5.0
    npm  : 4.1.2
    OS   : Windows 10
```

Answer (score 5):

**TLDR**

The following is a temporary solution:

Change the cordova-android dependency in your package.json file at the project root to

```
"cordova-android": "~6.2.3"
```

and then push to ionic master. Note - Changing the android engine in config.xml does not seem to fix the issue

**The issue**

The issue here is that the cordova-android 6.3.x uses Android-26. Ionic Pro Package appears to not yet have Android 26 available in their package service. The temporary solution therefore is to downgrade cordova-android to 6.2.3 which uses Android-26. Most likely the following files are configured as follows:

config.xml

```
<engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
```

package.json

```
"cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
```

The ^ in both configs specifies to use the latest 6.X.X version of the plugin, in this case 6.3.X. Changing the ^ to a ~ specifies using the latest 6.2.X. Making the change in the config.xml does not solve the issue as I believe that this is an Ionic Pro Package build issue where Ionic Pro Package references the Cordova-android version specified in config.js to launch determine which android sdk version to use. This is the reason that the cordova-android version needs to be changed in the package.json for the time being to downgrade the android sdk version to 25 until Ionic Pro has updated their service to support android sdk 26

Comment: I love you and I want to make babies with you. Thank you for this response.